# whats the best to test a link in site as part of e2e test

Tags: automation, automated-tests

we have a page with several links and our automation clicks on a link and checks if it does not give a 404 and if the link has our company name. Is this a good way to test links in a page or is there is a better way to test links as part of e2e?

Comment: seems legit, paste the code maybe someone can give suggestions for optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we need to click all the links one by one and verify the links should not broken. This is how we do in manual testing right? It should still implies the same in test automation.

For the verification part, you may also include some more testing on the page that you just clicked:

1. Validate the locator or specific web element is present there (can check it's xpath).
2. Validate some text should contain on that page as expected.
3. We can also check how many seconds it takes to completely load the page. So, you can find out if there is any web page/link is having bad response time. Every test automation framework has different way to do this.